# validation for special character in textbox inside Telerik Grid

Tags: jquery, vb.net, vba

i am working on vb.net project. i need to validate inserted text of textbox that this text is not special character inside Telerik grid. this validation only allow space not any other special characters in vb.net or using jquery.how to do it? i have searched a lot but not find proper result.please help me to get the solution.

```
<script>
     function OnTextKeyPress(objEvent) {
         var $th = objEvent.value;
         $("#" + objEvent.id).val($th.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, function (str) {
         //$("#" + objEvent.id).val($th.replace(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-].*?$/g, function (str) {
                return '' ;
         }));
     }
 </script>



  <ItemTemplate>                                                                          <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtSizeName" CssClass="form-control" Skin="" runat="server" placeholder="Name" Width="100%"                                                                           MaxLength="15" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' OnTextChanged="txtSizeName_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  onkeyup="return OnTextKeyPress(this)" >                                                                   </telerik:RadTextBox>
                                                                                </ItemTemplate>
```

this script allow only numbers and letters in but not allow to insert space and underscore i need to allow space and underscore in special character and not allow any other special character.

Comment: Please provide example data and the code you have tried so far. SO will not code this for you.

Comment: i have edit my question and add what i have tried please give me proper suggestion for that.

Comment: Good update. If you jump through your code line by line, at what line does it not do what you expect it to do?

Comment: i don't know which line not working i have just tried it but this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this is working.

```
  <script>
           function OnTextKeyPress(objEvent) {
               var $th = objEvent.value;
               $("#" + objEvent.id).val($th.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\_]*$/g, function (str) {
                   return '';
               }));
           }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is Linq or Regex but the variety of Char methods might do the trick.

```
Private Sub CheckForSpecialChar()
        For Each c As Char In TextBox1.Text
            If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) Then
                'Do something
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Here are some other Char methods that might be helpful

- IsControl - Control character
- IsDigit -decimal digit
- IsLetter
- IsLetterOrDigit
- IsNumber
- IsPunctuation
- IsSepatator
- IsSymbol
- IsWhiteSpace